# Flash cs5 anti-decompiler?

Tags: flash

Is there any tool that prevents decompilation ?

I stumbled once upon a flash file that would crash when I tried to decompile it. So would like to know which product could do so.

Comment: Nothing can *prevent* decompilation of any format, but you can always obfuscate your code to make it harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CS5 files are based on the new XFL format, which is no more than a zip file, xml and assets:

http://blog.zarate.tv/2010/04/18/xfl-finally/

Didn't know when I wrote the post, but even FLA files coming out CS5 are only XFL files, but compressed.

All this means that is highly unlikely that you would find a tool to prevent decompilation, specially once the specs are out.

Cheers,

J

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can obfuscate your code - with this for example:

http://www.ambiera.com/irrfuscator/index.html